# Create Surface View With Child View

Tags: android

HI I want to create a surface view, and on the surface view i want three text views like
One text view Gravity left, center, Right. I need to use that surface view further in PixelFormat.RGBA_4444. How to Add Multiple text views and image views on the surface view. I do a lot if R&D over it but does not work. 
Any Idea welcome!!!

Comment: What? Why don't you simply put the Texts and the Surfaceview in a RelativeLayout?

Comment: Can you give me any example for this?? I'm very new to this surface view and surface holder

Comment: Then how can convert the pixel format of that view into PixelFormat_ARGB4444??

Comment: it seems linke I'm getting you wrong. Please add extra info.. Also share some of your "R&D" please.

Comment: Yes, I need to capture surface view in the format of RGBA_4444 and send to android kernel. On the surface view i'm setting some text view, or icon. from R&D i had make the view and creates views on surface view. This i already done from R&D. But Now the problem is that how to get the surface holder to bitmap or draw on canvas.?? how to convert it but by not using Bitmap.Config.ARGB4444.